# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have such a code. But I am getting `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)` error in the codes.

```
const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
 final encryprionKey = secureStorage.read(key: 'key');
 if (encryprionKey == null) {
   final key = Hive.generateSecureKey();
   await secureStorage.write(
     key: 'key',
     value: base64UrlEncode(key),
   );
 }

 final key = await secureStorage.read(key: 'key');
 final encryptionKey = base64Url.decode(key!);
 print('Encryption key: $encryptionKey');
 final encryptedBox= await Hive.openBox('vaultBox', encryptionCipher: 
 HiveAesCipher(encryptionKey));
 encryptedBox.put('secret', 'Hive is cool');
 print(encryptedBox.get('secret'));
```

[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: What is the stack trace, and what is the offending line?  When you call `base64Url.decode(key!)`, are you sure that `key` cannot be `null`?

Comment: @jamesdlin The key is already generated. That is, data is saved beforehand.

Comment: Probably the `key` was not generated/saved, try to print it to see if it's not `== null`

Comment: On this line `if (encryprionKey == null) { `, what is the warning?

Comment: @Belinda G. Freitas `The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.
Try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement.`

Comment: Then if `encryprionKey` is a String try using `if(encryprionKey.isNotEmpty) {`. Have you checked the value of `key` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`final encryprionKey = secureStorage.read(key: 'key');` neglects to `await` the result of the `secureStorage.read`.  The returned `Future` itself is never `null`, so the `if (encryprionKey == null)` check is never true, nothing is ever written, and the second `secureStorage.read` call (which *is* `await`ed) will get back `null`.

This is why the Dart analyzer warned you that the `if (encryprionKey == null)` condition is always false.  Enabling the [`unawaited_futures`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html) lint would have generated an additional (and perhaps clearer) warning.

Not having separate variables for the two calls to `secureStorage.read` also would have caught this as a compilation error:

```dart
  const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  var encryprionKey = secureStorage.read(key: 'key');
  if (encryprionKey == null) {
    final key = Hive.generateSecureKey();
    await secureStorage.write(
      key: 'key',
      value: base64UrlEncode(key),
    );
  }

  // This line would have generated a TypeError.
  encryprionKey = await secureStorage.read(key: 'key');
```

In this case, it'd better to reassign the `encryprionKey` (sic) variable than to make it `final` with a separate `key` variable.  Having separate variables to represent the same thing is more confusing and is error-prone.